# How to run "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates" inside a Dokerfile?

Tags: docker, certificates

I have to add my own CA certificate inside a docker container.

When I try to run the command "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates" inside the Dockerfile it fails because cannot use the interactive interface.

How can I run interactively inside the dockerfile?

Or is it possible to tell "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates" to enable all certificates without asking?

This is the Dockerfile:

```
# Docker Image which is used as foundation to create
# a custom Docker Image with this Dockerfile
FROM node:15

ENV NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/usr/src/app/mrootca.pem
ENV TERM=xterm

# A directory within the virtualized Docker environment
# Becomes more relevant when using Docker Compose later
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install CA cetificare in the OS
COPY ./mrootca.pem /usr/share/ca-certificates/mrootca.crt
RUN dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
 
# Copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package*.json ./
COPY mrootca.pem ./
 
# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install
 
# Copies everything over to Docker environment
COPY . .
 
# Uses port which is used by the actual application
EXPOSE 3000
 
# Finally runs the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The docker image is generated with the command:

```
docker build --tag fpresenter:v1 .
```

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive ca-certificates`

But you don't have to run that command at all, just call `update-ca-certificates` which collects (by default) **all** certificates from `/usr/share/ca-certificates/*.crt` and `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/*.crt` and will link all of them to `/etc/ssl/certs/`, runs `c_rehash` for fast lookup and will build `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` containing all certificates.

If you want to disable some certificates — or enable just a few — you can (de-)select them via the file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`, which the original command generates.